# Not able to get data from request in Junit when action class implements ParameterAware

Tags: java, unit-testing, struts2, junit3

I need to write jUnit for Struts 2 action class.But action class is implementing `ParameterAware` interceptor which takes parameter map in `HashMap` and action class takes all request parameter from this hashmap

**Action Class:**

```
public class BrokerAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware,SessionAware,
        ParameterAware {

    /** The parameters. */
    private Map parameters;

    @Override
    public void setParameters(final Map param) {
        this.parameters = param;
    }

   public String getParameterValue(final String param) {
        final Object varr = getParameters().get(param);
        if (varr == null) {
            return null;    
        }
        return ((String[]) varr)[0];
    }

   public String getBrokerDetails()throws PactException{
        String id = getParameterValue("id");
   }
```

When i am putting data from Junit in request then it hasn't reflected in parameters map

**Junit:**

```
@Test
     public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {
        
         request.setAttribute("id", "23");
         ActionProxy proxy   =  getActionProxy("/getBrokerDetails");
         BrokerAction brokerAction = (BrokerAction) proxy.getAction();
         brokerAction.getBrokerDetails();
    }
```

Please help as how request data will be reflected in parameters map

Comment: Attribute != parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests should be simple - instead of setting attributes on a request and using ActionProxy, why not just call `setParameters` to set your parameters? If your unit test is calling out to code that isn't in the class you are testing, then it becomes more complex and prone to failure for reasons not related to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.That what i am doing currently but was curious that if action implements ParameterAware or SessionAware, which are struts inteceptor, so can we test inteceptor chain also via junit?

Comment: There's also unclear which `setParameters` to call, so this is not an answer.

Comment: There is only 1 method called setParameters in the provided code, I think its pretty clear

Comment: @codebox you should not call *setParameters in the provided code*, because it's already done via servlet config interceptor.

Comment: I don't think a true unit test should be running things like interceptors, that's more a job for integration testing. A unit test should run the smallest unit of code possible, there is no need to involve framework code in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The code to test the request parameter

```
<package name="test" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getBrokerDetails" class="BrokerAction ">
        <result>/page.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>


 public void testGetActionProxy() throws Exception {

     request.setParameter("id", "23");
     ActionProxy proxy   =  getActionProxy("/getBrokerDetails");
     BrokerAction brokerAction = (BrokerAction) proxy.getAction();

     String result = proxy.execute();
     assertEquals(Action.SUCCESS, result);

     assertEquals("23", brokerAction.getBrokerDetails());

}
```

Comment: request.setParameter("id", "23"); does not make parameter available in parameter map of ParameterAware